# How do web apps receive/process uploaded images?

Tags: django, networking, web-applications, file-upload

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. How do websites create forms for image uploads, store, and process it for display on their sites? My current situation is with django storing images.

Answer (score 1):

You place a `<form>` on your page. It can have different inputs in it, like text, numbers, etc. There is also `file` input. Then the user submits the form and all data is sent to the webserver. The webserver, basically, receives the file as an array of bytes. You can read more about it [here](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html).

In case of Django you'll receive this data in `request.FILES`. You'll get name, size and other data of the file selected by user. You can then save it on disk or in your database. Read about Django-specific things [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Answer (score 1):

In general (in a very resumed/simplistic way):

1. A web page renders a form with an  widget in it.
2. When you tell the browser what's the file you want to upload, it prepare an HTTP request to the webserver in which it stores the binary data of the file.
3. The request is sent to the web server through a TCP connection.
4. The server takes the request, see the file an decides what to do with it (depending on configuration files)
5. Later, the program handling the request, ask the global variables of the server (or something like that) what the heck it did with it files
6. The server give it the address where it was stored
7. The app do the rest of the job with the file uploaded :)

In Django:

1. Three first step are the same
2. The server ask django what to do with the file
3. Depending on `settings.py` the file is uploaded to memory or to a temporary file in disk
4. The application handles the file accessing it to `request.FILES` dictionary in your view
5. When you have it, you can pass it to your models, forms or do whatever you want.

If you want to go deeper with Django file uploads, [this section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) is really good. You can take a look at it.

Hope this helps!